# Defining a list in R using the same variable names

Tags: r, list

This is a fairly basic question.  I want to define a list in R. The names of this list are to be the same names of the vectors that were used to create a list.

Better to write a short code example.  This is what I want.

But using the same names twice in the list of arguments seems a really clumsy way of doing this!

```
vct_numbers <- c(1,2,3,4)
vct_colours <- c("blue", "green", "yellow")
lst_coll <- list(vct_numbers = vct_numbers, vct_colours  = vct_colours)
```

Is there a better / more elegant way of doing this...?

Comment: You've got the best way.  Any other way to do it would require a lot of nonstandard evaluation and additional coding.  Your code would be less readable to other R users in any other method.